# The meaning of should

Tags: grammar

"Why shouldn't I be able to use all the resources here?"

Is this "should" the same as "I should go it." or "Why should I believe that story?"

Thank you.

Comment: I should "go" it? Shouldn't it be, "I should *do* it"?

Comment: You may be interested in our companion site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, it's slightly different. This sentence contains **two** modals (_should-_ and _be able_), one quantifier (_all_), and one negative (_-n't_); plus it's a _Wh_-question, which is a negative trigger. That means it's ***really*** complex, no matter how simple it looks, and the interpretation of _should_ is going to be very specific to this context.

Comment: This question belongs on English Language Learners

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm pretty sure it is.

'Should' is a *modal auxiliary verb* used mainly to:
i) *show **obligation*** - as in "You should have helped the old woman."
ii) *show **expectation*** - "I should be home by 2 p.m."

It has a few other uses which you can look up [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Shall_and_should).